# Android: how to format a html string to be displayed in a webview?

Tags: android, html, webview

Here is why I want to do.
I have an html string extracted from a rss feed.
I want it to display nicely in a WebView embedded in my activity.
I can easily do it using the loadData() function, but the display isn't optimized for a small device : in another word I want to resize the html content not to exceed my view width.
So images, frames, tables need to be resized.

How can I do it ?
I thought I could use Google Wireless Transcoder service but it only works with urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use css, but it depends on the feed (each post might have different formatting / apply styles inline)
Use [loadDataWithBaseURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), with "file:///android_asset/" as the base url. Put a css file in your /project/assets folder. Inject the css file into the  tag of your html.

Comment: I thought about something like that but because I can't assume anything about the incoming feed, how can I build a global css that will allways work ?

Comment: in css injection what should be there exactly because my html have only an image that i need to load